# Cleveref: Multiple letters inside parentheses for subfigures

Tags: cleveref

I am using `cleveref` with `crefmultiformat` to reference a list of subfigures. I would like to have the letters referencing the subfigure of the main figure listed inside parentheses, like so: figs. 1(a,b)

The output that I get using the code below is: figs. 1a(,b)

How can it be achieved?

```
\documentclass[11pt,
               twoside,
               a4paper,
               english,
               abstract=off,
               headsepline=on,
               captions=tableheading]
               {scrartcl}     
              
              
\usepackage[]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref} 


 \crefmultiformat{figure}
 {figs.~#2#1\xdef\mycreffirstarg{#1}(#3}
 {,#2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3)}
 {,#2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}
 {,#2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3)}
    
\begin{document}
 
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    {\phantomsubcaption\ignorespaces\label{subfig:fig-a}}
    {\phantomsubcaption\ignorespaces\label{subfig:fig-b}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example}
    \label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

The output that I would like to get is: figs. 1(a,b) 

The output that I get is: \cref{subfig:fig-a,subfig:fig-b}

 
 \end{document}
```

[image]